# Same content, different MD5 - File and String

Tags: c++, c, md5

1. I have a file `testfile` and a string `teststring`.
2. In a shell I wrote:
   `echo "a" > testfile`
3. then `xxd testfile`
   so I can see the hexadecimal values of my filecontent
   output:

   ```
   0000000: 610a               a.
   ```
4. see my code:

   ```
   int file;
   struct stat s;
   unsigned long size;
   char* buffer;
   char md5[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]

   file = open("testfile", O_RDONLY);
   if (file < 0)
       return false;

   if (fstat(file, &s) < 0)
   {
       close(file);
       return false;
   }

   size = s.st_size;                       //GET FILE SIZE
   printf("filesize: %lu\n", size);        //PRINT FILESIZE FOR DEBUGGING
   buffer = (char*)mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, file, 0); //MAP FILE CONTENT TO BUFFER
   MD5((unsigned char*)buffer, size, md5); //GENERATE MD5
   munmap(buffer, size);                   //UNMAP BUFFER
   close(file);

   for (int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
       printf("%02x", md5[i]);
   printf("\n");


   unsigned char* teststring = "\x61\x0a"; //SAME STRING AS IN THE FILE

   MD5((unsigned char*)teststring, 2, md5);
   for (int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
       printf("%02x", md5[i]);
   printf("\n");
   ```
5. it prints:

   ```
   filesize: 2  
   60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3  
   e29311f6f1bf1af907f9ef9f44b8328b
   ```

   two **completely different** md5 hashes.
   i tried writing the `buffer` into a file
   and writing the `teststring` into a file ***they are the same***!
   by why?
   isn't the `buffer` the same as the `teststring`?

Comment: I'm not a C/C++ programmer so I can't provide any overly technical help. What format is the file in (Unicode/ASCII etc)? Is the length of the buffer (once populated) the same as the teststring length?

Comment: yes, both have lenght = 2 chars; format = ascii

Comment: print the buffer / string in hex (not the md5s), see if they differ. if they are the same, you probably need to use the md5 function in a different way (some implementations require you to finish the md5 operation)

Comment: Why does xxd show `0000000: 610a               a.`? Why not `0000000: 610a               `?

Comment: how is `MD5` implemented ?

Comment: Maybe there's an EOF character in there?

Comment: MD5() is a function from openssl `#include <openssl/md5.h>`

Comment: Is the result the same, if you reverse the order of these two methods? (I.e. the MD5 interface would _continue_ to update the checksum perhaps?)

Comment: yes, **exactly** the same, no matter of calling-order

Comment: @Pubby maybe, there are only two chars, 0x61 and 0x0a, but even if 0x0a would be EOF, would it matter in any way? both times MD5 calculates with size 2, meaning it is included

Comment: @RahulBanerjee because it outputs first the hexcode `610a` and then the ascii text `a.` the dot means a non display character (such as whitespaces, EOF, ...)

Comment: just do `printf("%02x", buffer[0]);printf("%02x", buffer[1]);` and `printf("%02x", teststring[0]);printf("%02x", teststring[1]);`. then you actually know if they are the same (which i think they are not). looking at the docs i think you use the md5 function correctly

Comment: Have you tried clearing the `md5` array before and between the calls?

Comment: As implied by @AkiSuihkonen it seems that the problem resides in the `MD5` function implementation. Otherwise, if the problem were in the buffering process, when you swap the calls, the results should be swapped too

Comment: I agree with Joachim Pileborg, are you just resusing the md5 again without resetting as this looks like you are not resetting the md5 state

Comment: @x4rf41 vote up! youre right, the string is `0x64 0x0a` and the file is `0x61 0x0a` but why? as you can see i typed ``teststring = "\x61\x0a"

Comment: What happens if you comment out everything related to the file processing, any only use the string related part?

Comment: thats really weird, whats the result with `teststring = "a."` ?

Comment: @x4rf41 that would be a completely different hash, because xxd shows a dot as whitspace characters (EOF, NEWLINE, etc.), to show that there is 'something'

Comment: I can not reproduce this. With the code above, it prints `60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3` in both cases (which is the same what the `md5sum` command shows for the `testfile`). I had to change `char md5` into `unsigned char md5` though. Can you provide a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which reproduces the issue? And include compiler version, openssl version and operating system?

Comment: See [GitHub](https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/md5issue) for a complete sample code which works. I only added a main function, include files and changed the signedness of two char variables to not get any warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct hash is your first hash, `60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3`.

```
$ echo "a" | md5
60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3
```

Your second hash happens to be the hash of "\x64\x0a", or the character 'd' followed by a newline:

```
$ echo "d" | md5
e29311f6f1bf1af907f9ef9f44b8328b
```

Are you sure the code you posted is what you are compiling/running? Did you forget to recompile? Are you executing an old binary?

Comment: "Are you sure the code you posted is what you are compiling?" -- Most likely not. `char md5[]` needs to be unsigned, `teststring` needs to be **not** unsigned to even make this compile in the first place...